# C++ nested for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-loops

I am newer at C++ and I am trying to get the number 50 to increment inside of the for loop. I need to print the number as it increments. It isn't printing or showing an error. I am trying to begin printing at 50 and increment from there

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main(){
    char kitchen[2][10] = {"Skillet", "Grill"};
    int price[2] = { 1, 2};
    int i;
    int k;

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for(k = 50; k < 50; k = k+1) {
            cout << k << "    " << price[i] << "    " << kitchen[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obviously, `for(k=50; k<50; k = k + 1)`.

Comment: How far do you want to increment `50` to? Currently it starts at `50` and end before `50`.

Comment: Always look for tutorials or working examples before posting such elementary questions - as its almost always a typo or something you could solve yourself by so simple research that you likely always get downvoted - and keep in mind http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am trying to count up from 50. So it would list 50, 51, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
for(k=50; k<50; k = k + 1){
```

to

```
for(k = 0; k < 50; k = k + 1){ //k = k + 1 or k++
```

Because when `k = 50`, `k < 50` condition become `false` and the body of the inner for loop never executed, hence nothing prints.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner for loop can not run because the condition is false even at the first iteration. Change it to the following

```
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for(k = 0; k < 50; k++) {
            cout << k << "    " << price[i] << "    " << kitchen[i] << endl;
        }
    }
```